# Integration of JSON-Validator in JSF-Input-Components?

Tags: json, jsf, integration, validation

i'd like to know, is there any available library/component that we can use/integrate directly in jsf-page, so that the user-input will be validated if it json-conformed?

Thank you guys for any hint!

Comment: You're going to have to roll your own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's as far as I know none. It is however not that hard to pick a [JSON parser to your choice](http://json.org) and invoke it in a custom `Validator`.

E.g.

```
@FacesValidator("jsonValidator")
public class JsonValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        try {
            SomeJsonParser.parse(value);
        } catch (SomeJsonException e) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Not in valid JSON format"));
        }
    }

}
```

Which is then used the usual way:

```
<h:inputTextarea value="#{bean.json}" validator="jsonValidator" />
```

Comment: Thank you. My solution until yesterday is to use javascript library jquery.parseJSON(input) as the front end validator.